# How to mod down a congruence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose I have a congruence $18y \equiv 1 \pmod 7$. How do I figure out how to mod it down to $4y \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ so it makes solving for $y$ much easier by dealing with the number $4$(small number instead of $18$(bigger number)?

Comment: Is the question why $18y = 4y$ (mod 7)?

Comment: Almost. Why is 18y = 1 (mod 7) equal to 4y(mod 7)?

Comment: In that case note that $18 = 7+7+4 = 4$ (mod 7). Then note that $18y = 18 + \ldots + 18$ for a total of $y$ times. Now each $18 = 4$ (mod 7), so $18y = 18 + \ldots + 18 = 4 + \ldots + 4 = 4y$ (mod 7). Accordingly solving $18y = 1$ (mod 7) is equal to solving $4y = 1$ (mod 7).

Comment: So basically you got the 4 from the remainder?

Comment: Yes, because 7 (mod 7) is equal to 0

Comment: What happens if there is an opposite effect? Suppose instead of 18 there was 7 and instead if 7 there was 18: like this 7y = 1 (mod 18)? Can I still mod it down?

Comment: Basically, because $18\equiv 4 \mod{7}$, we get that $18y\equiv 1\mod 7$ means $4y\equiv 1\mod 7$. Essentially, if $a\equiv b \mod n$ then $ax\equiv bx \mod n$.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite as:
$$18y = 2\cdot7y + 4y$$

Now, since $2\cdot7$ is divisible by $7$, we have $18y \equiv 4y \pmod 7$. So we can "mod it down" to $4y\equiv 1 \pmod 7$. In other words:

$$18y \equiv 1 \pmod 7 \iff 4y \equiv 1 \pmod 7$$
In general, for arbitrary integers $a,n,b,y$, we have (by the [distributive law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) of multiplication, if you fancy):

$$(an + b)y = any + by$$ Now, $an$ is divisible by $n$, so we can "mod  this down" to $(an+b)y \equiv by \pmod n$. So we have, in general, $$(an+b)y\equiv 1 \pmod n \iff by \equiv 1 \pmod n$$

---

As for the question in your comments, $7y \equiv 1 \pmod {18}$ is considered the "smallest" already, based on the context you have provided.

However, it is possible to "mod it down" even further by considering the [modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of $7$ modulo $18$ (in fact, the following method is not restricted to this case alone). It turns out that if we multiply both sides by $13$ (the modular inverse of $7$ modulus $18$), then we get:

$$7\cdot13y \equiv 13 \pmod{18}\\$$

But $7\cdot 13 = 91 = 5\cdot18 + 1$. Thus, as discussed earlier, we can say that $(5\cdot18 + 1)y \equiv 1\pmod{18}$, and therefore:

$$7\cdot13y \equiv 13 \pmod{18} \iff y\equiv 13 \pmod{18}$$

This is the simplest form I can possibly think of.